# Slow button response - need to click twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on HTML/JS script.
The aim is to get the button to change color and shows text when clicked based on corrrect/incorrect answer.
The code works (I am new to this language) but my main problem is that I need to click the button twice for the changes to shows.
I have already checked similar questions and found different solutions (eg. remove styles, or use type='submit' instead of type='button') but none works.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
 <!--       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
        <title>Test!</title>

        <script>
            function Q1_a()
            {
             document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").addEventListener("click", function(Q1_a)
                {
                  document.getElementById("res_q1_1").innerHTML = "incorrect";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                });
            document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").addEventListener("click", function(Q1_a)
                {
                  document.getElementById("res_q1_1").innerHTML = "correct";
                  document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                 });
            document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").addEventListener("click", function(Q1_a)
                {
                  document.getElementById("res_q1_1").innerHTML = "incorrect";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                });
             }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Event </h1>

                <h2>Multiple choice </h2>
                <hr>
                <h3> How many chairs do we need? </h3>
                <h3 id="res_q1_1" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
                 <p>
                    <form>
                        <button type="button" id="answerQ1_1" onclick="Q1_a()">6 chairs</button>
                        <button type="button" id="answerQ1_2" onclick="Q1_a()">2 chairs</button>
                        <button type="button" id="answerQ1_3" onclick="Q1_a()">1 chair</button>
                    </form>
                </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the onclick html attribute to run code that itself adds event listeners to your buttons. So when you click the button the first time, all the buttons get new event listeners added, and when you click the second time, those listeners fire. Remove function `Q1_a`, but keep its content. Also, move this whole script block to the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag (or defer it, or run the content on load... but just moving it to the bottom works quite well). That way it will run after the elements are on the page.

```js
             document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").addEventListener("click", function(Q1_a)
                {
                   document.getElementById("res_q1_1").innerHTML = "incorrect";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                });
            document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").addEventListener("click", function(Q1_a)
                {
                   document.getElementById("res_q1_1").innerHTML = "correct";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                 });
            document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").addEventListener("click", function(Q1_a)
                {
                   document.getElementById("res_q1_1").innerHTML = "incorrect";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_1").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                   document.getElementById("answerQ1_2").style.backgroundColor = " #f5f5f5";
                });
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>Test!</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Event </h1>

                <h2>Multiple choice </h2>
                <hr>
                <h3> How many chairs do we need? </h3>
                <h3 id="res_q1_1" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
                 
                    <form>
                        <button type="button" id="answerQ1_1">6 chairs</button>
                        <button type="button" id="answerQ1_2">2 chairs</button>
                        <button type="button" id="answerQ1_3">1 chair</button>
                    </form>
                
    </body>
</html>
```